# How to add a where clause to a Hibernate @ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, many-to-many, join, hibernate-filters

Given two entities:

- `PurchaseProductGroup`
- `PurchaseProduct`, which has a `status` column that can be `'A'` (active) or `'D'` (deleted)

and a many-to-many relationship defined in `PurchaseProductGroup`:

```
/** The purchase products linked to this group. */
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "purchaseprodgrp_purchaseprod",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ppg_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ppr_id"))
private List<PurchaseProduct> purchaseProducts;
```

How can I restrict this so that purchaseProducts with a status of `'D'` are excluded?

### Things I've tried

Have tried adding the following just below the `@ManyToMany` annotation but both failed with an "invalid identifier" exception for the column:

1. `@Where(clause = "status <> 'D'")`
2. `@WhereJoinTable(clause = "purchaseProduct.status <> 'D'")`

Also tried using adding `@Where(clause = "status <> 'D'")` at the entity level but this doesn't seem to affect the contents of relationship collections - as backed up by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892665).

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly have in mind is possible with Hibernate.  We can add a check constraint, if supported, on the `status` column itself, but that would exclude all `'D'` values entirely from the table.  The method you might end up going with is just to add a `WHERE` clause to your query.  Not the worst thing at all, by the way, especially if you tune your query properly.

Comment: Would rather the deleted records were always excluded when working with the entities themselves in code (as opposed to using explicit queries). The first suggestion of putting a constraint on the column itself seems a good one, please could you explain further how to do this?

Comment: No, the constraint approach won't work for you, because it would prevent _all_ records having `'D'` from ever even making it into the database.  I would probably just go with a `WHERE` clause here.  Anyway, the logic of how you extract your actual data belongs in the query side of things IMO.

Comment: I presume the constraint approach would be putting `@Where(clause = "status <> 'D'")` at the top of the `PurchaseProduct` entity. Are you saying this would actually prevent the delete from working if it tried to update a persisted `PurchaseProduct` by calling `setStatus('D')` on it?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us exactly where you placed the `@Where` and `@WhereJoinTable` annotations.

Comment: OK - have edited it - also to mention that unfortunately a `@Where` clause at entity level doesn't seem to affect the contents of related entity collections (such as `purchaseProducts` above).

Comment: Is `status` the actual name of the field in the `PurchaseProduct` class?

Comment: Yes it is but is isn't the same as the name of the column in the database, which is named `ppr_status`. Am just investigating whether this needs to be used instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "purchaseprodgrp_purchaseprod",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ppg_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ppr_id"))
@Where(clause = "ppr_status <> 'D'")
private List<PurchaseProduct> purchaseProducts;
```

This may be similar to something you have tried before, but a critical point to get this working is that `ppr_status` is the actual column name.  Hence the `PurchaseProduct` entity should have the following:

```
@Column(name="ppr_status")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

If you had named the field `ppr_status` then the `@Column` may not be necessary.  But based on your comments above we need to tell Hibernate how to map this column.

Reference: [Hibernate annotations. @Where vs @WhereJoinTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504002/hibernate-annotations-where-vs-wherejointable)

Comment: Great, this works perfectly, thanks for the help! Have now raised a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692844).

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks, and apologies for my earlier comments, as I am not a guru in all parts of the Hibernate API.